Default terminal can't be changed after 24.04 update
I used to use the Tilix terminal instead of the default GNOME terminal.
Since the update to 24.04 I can't set it to default even if it's already set to default.
gsettings:

x-terminal-emulator:

I have tried many things, but the default terminal is still gnome-terminal.
Examples:

Ctrl+Alt+T => gnome-terminal
Nautilus right-click => gnome-terminal


Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you also include a scenario in which you are facing this issue?? Cause I can launch the Tilix using  Ctrl+Alt+t but not through Nautilus.
